# Why do i get infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

```
public class Spreadsheet {

    public static final int row = 10;
    public static final int column = 7;
    static Cell[][] data;

    public static void print() {
        data = new Cell[column][row];
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%13s","|");
                }
                    System.out.println();
                for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    for(int k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
                        System.out.print("_");
                    }
                        System.out.print("+");
                }
                    System.out.println();
            }
    }
```

this should print out a 10x7 spreadsheet but it doesn't do that. seems like an infinite loop error here. help?

Comment: When do you re-prompt the user for more commands?

Comment: if you ask for nextLine outside the loop you never get the next line.

Answer (score 5):

You only request user input once, and then keep re-using the same input. You can fix as follows:

```
while(input.hasNext()) {
    String userInput = input.nextLine();

    if (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
        commandLoop(userInput);
    }
}
```

You can also cram the assignment and evaluation of the condition in the `while` condition, but I find it to be less readable.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. Not fully awake yet :-)

Comment: hehehe, know that feeling ;)