# Use a While loop to add to array list

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

I have an array list containing books. What I am trying to do (for various reasons) is use a While loop to keep on adding books to my array list until I tell the program to stop. In order to get it to stop, I am using a Scanner to ask the human user if another book should be added. If the user says yes, then the method would repeat, otherwise, the method will stop.

Unfortunately, I am stuck in 2 areas (for now). First, I am not sure how to insert the decision into the method, I tried:

```
while(decision.equals("Yes"){addBooks(anyTitle,anyAuthor);},
```

however, that just seemed wrong as it goes into a loop (while I want), however it causes 2 issues: A)Even if I type something else, the method does not end (unless I use another scanner and include a break), and B) The same inputted fields get inserted into the array list over and over again, without giving me a chance to input new Strings.

```
/**
 * Method to add a single book
 */
public void setOneBook(String anyTitle, String anyAuthor){
    bookList.add (new Book(anyTitle,anyAuthor));
}

/**
 * Method to add books to collection until the command to stop is given.
 */
public void addBooks(String anyTitle, String anyAuthor){
    bookList.add (new Book(anyTitle,anyAuthor));
    System.out.println("Would you like to add another book?");
    String decision = keybd.next();
}
```

I'm feeling pretty dumb at the moment, so please keep any snide comments to yourself.

While this is up, I will be messing around with my code, so if anything changes (for better or for worse), I will update my post.

Comment: The `decision` you declare inside `addBooks()` is not the same variable as the one controlling your loop, because in Java [everything is passed by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds very similar to what I've proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28575639/3558960).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate the logic of asking the question for more information from that of updating the list

```
String decision = "No";
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to add another book?");
    decision = keybd.nextLine();
    if (decision.equals("Yes")) {
        // Get information about book
        String anyTitle = keybd.nextLine();
        String anyAuthor = keybd.nextLine();
        addBooks(anyTitle,anyAuthor);
    }
} while (decision.equals("Yes"));
```

You could go a step further, making a `addBook` method which prompts the user for the informaiton...

```
public void addBook() {
    String anyTitle = keybd.nextLine();
    String anyAuthor = keybd.nextLine();
    addBooks(anyTitle,anyAuthor);
}
```

Then you could just call `addBook` from the `while-loop`

```
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to add another book?");
    String decision = keybd.nextLine();
    if (decision.equals("Yes")) {
        addBook();
    }
} while (decision.equals("Yes"));
```

Further decoupling your code, allowing you to call `addBook` whenever you want to prompt the user for information about the book and adding it to the list

Comment: Three questions about the first part of your answer:  1) Based on what you suggested, the decisions variable is not able to be found. I tried a few things, but they did not help. 2) If the method name is :                             public void addBooks(String anyTitle, String anyAuthor)  then would they even need to be identified as Strings again in the coding? 3) Even putting aside the other two questions, when I do get it to work, it does not give me any place to enter information for the book even though it shows that the program is running.

Comment: 1- `decision` should be declared before the `do` loop starts, corrected; 2- Yes, because the parameters to the method only have context/meaning within the method, to the rest of the code, they are just place holds through which you pass information; 3- Then the condition which allows the user to enter the book information isn't been met, remember, `equals` is case sensitive, so you must enter "Yes" exactly

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your various snippets of code, I would strongly recommend you consider something that calls your method `setOneBook`... but I suggest you change the method visibility (and name) -

```
private void addOneBook(String anyTitle, String anyAuthor){
    bookList.add (new Book(anyTitle,anyAuthor));
}
```

This way you have used [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#General_definition) to hide the method that adds a book. Next, change the public method. You are adding multiple books, so don't pass in a title or an author -

```
public void addBooks() {
    do {
        String anyTitle = keybd.nextLine();
        String anyAuthor = keybd.nextLine();
        addOneBook(anyTitle, anyAuthor);
        System.out.println("Would you like to add another book?");
    } while (keybd.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}
```